# Something Known by Multiple Names

Tags: word-choice

Is there a word that means: someone or something that can be known by multiple names? A few examples:

- Rooster can also be referred to as a cock
- Soft drink also known as a soda, pop, Coke, etc.

A synonym is the closest descriptor I'm aware of, but it appears to apply to words, not people or things. Likewise, an alias refers to the name, not the person or object itself.

Thanks for helping me solve this!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The word you are looking for is

> [polyonymous](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/polyonymous)

From the Greek. Poly = many, onyma = name.

(Also note hilarious facebook comment "I heard it on wife swap" )

Comment: Thank you Archer, err Chris. It had been driving me nuts. Looking for synonyms of synonym or some such.